# iOS - MLKitImageLabeling while setting confidence to Imagelabeler app crash

Tags: ios, swift, image, label, firebase-mlkit

When ever I try to set `confidenceThreshold` to `ImageLabeler.imageLabeler(options:)` app crashes with Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MLKInvalidOptions', reason:
> 'Labeler options have invalid type.'

Code snap:

```
let responseBaseAccuracy: Double = 0.63
var lOption = ImageLabelerOptions()
lOption.confidenceThreshold = NSNumber(value: responseBaseAccuracy)
let onDeviceLabeler = ImageLabeler.imageLabeler(options: strongSelf.lOption) [Crash at this line]
```

**2 more lines from debugger before crash message**

> 2023-04-12 16:08:29.917030+0530 tdiag[3172:984324]  -
> [GoogleUtilitiesComponents][I-COM000001] Attempted to register
> protocol MLKCustomModelManagerInterop, but it already has an
> implementation.
>
> 2023-04-12 16:08:29.917401+0530 tdiag[3172:984324]  -
> [GoogleUtilitiesComponents][I-COM000001] Attempted to register
> protocol MLKDefaultImageLabelerRegistryInterop, but it already has an
> implementation.
>
> 2023-04-12 16:08:46.320130+0530 tdiag[3172:984314] *** Terminating app
> due to uncaught exception 'MLKInvalidOptions', reason: 'Labeler
> options have invalid type.'

**Note:**

- Using Xcode 14.3
- iOS deployment target 13.0
- use in .framework
- pod using `pod 'GoogleMLKit/ImageLabeling', '4.0.0'`